# What is the product of bessel functions of first and second kind when their arguments are same and tends to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, exponential-function

As we know, $\lim_{x \to 0} J_m(x)=0$ where $m\geq 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} Y_m(x)=\infty$ then what would be $\lim_{x \to 0}J_m(x)Y_m(x)$. Matlab shows the product is finite and $< 1$. What should I consider logically?

Since

1. $0\times \infty=0$
2. $0\times \infty=\frac{\infty}{\infty}=$ Undefined

Comment: It depends on their rates of convergence. This is a job for L'Hopital's rule

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: The limit you describe is an indeterminate form. What the answer will be depends on the functions. Example: $3x \to \infty$ and $1/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ but $\lim_{x \to \infty} 3x(1/x) = 3$. If I take $\lim_{x \to \infty} (3x^2)(1/x)$ instead I get $\infty$, and if I take $\lim_{x \to \infty} 3x(1/x^2)$ I get $0$. It all depends on *how fast* the constituent limits converge. But to make the determination, in general you will need L'Hopital's rule (when the functions are differentiable).

Comment: Since you're using Matlab, why not employ symbolic math for this simple case?: `syms z;` `limit(besselj(1,z)*bessely(1,z),z,0)` – or are you looking for a closed form as a function of `m`?

Comment: Thanks. I have used Matlab with your suggestion and found the limiting value as $-\frac{1}{m\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the asymptotic expansions (Abramowitz and Stegun, p. 360) for small $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \geq 0$:

$$ J_n(z) \sim \left(\frac{1}{2}z \right)^n (\Gamma(n+1))^{-1}, \quad Y_n \sim - \frac{1}{\pi}\Gamma(n)\left(\frac{1}{2}z\right)^{-n},$$ 
to get 
$$ \lim_{z \to 0} Y_n(z) J_n(z) = - \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\pi\Gamma(n+1)} < 1.  $$